# Yii2 dependency injection example

Tags: php, dependency-injection, yii2

Can someone point me in the direction of a practical example or tutorial using the DI container in Yii2?

I must be thick but the 2.0 guide on this subject is just not that clear to me.  Also, most on-line tutorial and sample code I have reviewed is peppered with the `Yii::$app` singleton, which makes testing difficult.

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-di-container.html#registering-dependencies

Comment: Why don't you ask exactly what is not clear to you?

Answer (score 6):

For example you have classes `\app\components\First` and `\app\components\Second` implements one interface `\app\components\MyInterface`

You can use DI container to change class only in one place. For example:

```
class First  implements MyInterface{
    public function test()
    {
        echo "First  class";
    }
}
class Second implements MyInterface {
    public function test()
    {
        echo "Second  class";
    }
}

$container= new \yii\di\Container();
$container->set ("\app\components\MyInterface","\app\components\First");
```

Now you give instance of First class  when calling `$container->get("\app\components\MyInterface");`

```
$obj = $container->get("\app\components\MyInterface");
$obj->test(); // print "First  class"
```

But now we can set other class for this interface.

```
$container->set ("\app\components\MyInterface","\app\components\Second");
$obj = $container->get("\app\components\MyInterface");
$obj->test(); // print "Second class"
```

You can set classes in one place and other code will used new class automatically.

[Here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-di-container.html) you can find great documentation for this pattern in Yii with code examples.

Answer (score 3):

this is a simple example to set default widget settings:

```
        // Gridview default settings
        $gridviewSettings = [
            'export' => false,
            'responsive' => true,
            'floatHeader' => true,
            'floatHeaderOptions' => ['scrollingTop' => 88],
            'hover' => true,
            'pjax' => true,
            'pjaxSettings' => [
                'options' => [
                    'id' => 'grid-pjax',
                ],
            ],
            'resizableColumns' => false,
        ];

        Yii::$container->set('kartik\grid\GridView', $gridviewSettings);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have some similar requirement where I want to start new project with Yii2 because of
production readiness but eventually I would move to yii3 once it become production ready. To keep the migration easy, it is recommended from yii to replace Yii::$app with dependency injection and that's where I need to implement dependency injections for my components to be used in controllers.

Here is my component.

```
<?php

namespace common\services;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Component;

class HelloService extends Component
{
    public function welcome() {
        echo "Welcome from service component";
    }
}
```

Here is my controller using above component and accessing it through dependency injection.

```
<?php
namespace console\controllers;

use yii\console\Controller;
use common\services\HelloService;

class HelloController extends Controller
{
    public $message;
    /** @var common\services\HelloService $helloService */
    private $helloService;

    public function __construct($id, $module, HelloService $helloService, $config = [])
    {
        $this->helloService = $helloService;
        parent::__construct($id, $module, $config);
    }
    
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        echo $this->helloService->welcome() . "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you pass HelloService  to your controller?